# Is it possible to initialize the keys and values of a HashMap from a List of keys, setting values to 0

Tags: java

So I have an array list:

```
static List<Integer> KEYS = Arrays.asList(KEY1, KEY2, KEY3);
```

and I need to create a `HashMap<Integer, Double>`
whereby the keys are KEYS, and the values are initialized to 0D.

Can I do this in one line of code?

Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using java-8 stream you can stream the list and collect them into Map

```
Map<Integer, Double> map = KEYS.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), i -> 0d));
```

Comment: Thx - I had tried that, but was missing the "i -> ". Working now :-)